# How To implement abstract function which uses data members of parent class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I have the following abstract class :

```
abstract class OutDoorGames
{
    protected String name;
    protected int num_players;
    protected int min_of_play;

    abstract void game (String a,int g,int r);
};
```

I want the `public void game` function to assign values to the data members to the objects.

This Is The Class Which Implements The  `abstract void game (String a,int g,int r)`  :

```
class Cricket extends OuterDoorGames
{
    public void game (String name,int num_players,int min_of_play)
    {
        OutDoorGames::name = name ; 
        OutDoorGames::num_players = num_players ; 
        OutDoorGames::min_of_play = min_of_play ; 
    }
}
```

But its giving Error When Compiled..

I also tried this :

```
class Cricket extends OuterDoorGames
{
    public void game (String name,int num_players,int min_of_play)
    {
        this.name = name ; 
        this.num_players = num_players ; 
        this.min_of_play = min_of_play ; 
    }
}
```

This is also not working...
I am new to Java...How Should I Implement This Function.....??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you got the names wrong.. Notice the name you gave to the parent abstract class `OutDoorGames` is not the same as you wrote when extended it `OuterDoorGames`.

As a practice, you can also try making a constructor in the parent abstract class which sets the 3 members and then just call it from within the constructor of the child class

An example of such usage:

```
public abstract class Bicycle {

// the Bicycle class has three fields
public int cadence;
public int gear;
public int speed;

// the Bicycle class has one constructor
public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
    gear = startGear;
    cadence = startCadence;
    speed = startSpeed;
}

// the Bicycle class has four methods
public void setCadence(int newValue) {
    cadence = newValue;
}

public void setGear(int newValue) {
    gear = newValue;
}

public void applyBrake(int decrement) {
    speed -= decrement;
}

public void speedUp(int increment) {
    speed += increment;
}    }

    public class MountainBike extends Bicycle {

    // the MountainBike subclass adds one field
    public int seatHeight;

    // the MountainBike subclass has one constructor
    public MountainBike(int startHeight,
                        int startCadence,
                        int startSpeed,
                        int startGear) {
        super(startCadence, startSpeed, startGear);
        seatHeight = startHeight;
    }   

    // the MountainBike subclass adds one method
    public void setHeight(int newValue) {
        seatHeight = newValue;
    }   
}
```

Notice the `super` call which activates the parent class constructor. Just change it to accept your 3 arguments in the parent class

Answer (score 1):

> class Cricket extends OuterDoorGames

If you are getting a `OuterDoorGames cannot be resolved to a type`, then it's a typo. Your abstract class is named as "OutDoorGames". Once you correct that, your Cricket class should just work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I can see with the second one is that the class name is wrong. The first class you defined (your abstract class) is called "OutDoorGames", but you're trying to extend "OuterDoorGames".